# Apache axis Library

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis, ioexception

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize a java.lang.String with the ArraySerializer!

when i am trying to run my web services program i was getting this error! Your help is highly appreciated. As i am new user it may take some time to get all the rules and regulations of StackOverflow.

Comment: so this is a notice to us or something else

Comment: there isn't even a question at all?

Comment: post your code as well please

Comment: sorry, i forgot to insert the question.

Comment: public XMLStringUtils(String xmlStr) throws Exception {
    try {
       this.xmlString = xmlStr;
 
      this.factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
 
      this.builder = this.factory.newDocumentBuilder();
/*    */ 
/* 40 */      this.doc = this.builder.parse(new **ByteArrayInputStream(this.xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8")));**
//this.doc = this.builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.xmlString.getBytes())).setEncoding("UTF-8"));


       this.xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
 
       this.xpath = this.xpathFactory.newXPath();     }

Comment: Don't put the code as a comment, edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no more detail than that,

- You passed a `String` where an array was expected by the server.
- But most probably, you passed a `String` where the WSDL specified an array.  In other words, the request didn't leave the client.

Comment: I just modified the code this.doc = this.builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.xmlString.getBytes())); to this.doc = this.builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8")));     After modifying the code i was getting the Apache axis error.